# Where does open sea and other website store NFT data?

Tags: nft, opensea

Where are the pictures, traits and transactions stored that we see on NFT marketplaces and collection sites?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about pictures, traits, and transactions. These three are different in terms of storage. This is how:

Pictures and traits: It depends on the collection's creator where they have stored the picture as the smart contract only has a link to a JSON file containing the traits and a link to the picture and what opensea does is fetch the image and show it on the front end.

transactions: Transactions are simply stored in the blockchain whatever the contract is deployed on.

I hope this helps.

If you want a more detailed explanation refer to this article: [ERC721](https://www.zaryabs.com/ethereum-token-standards-part-erc721/)

Comment: Which database solution is the best for storing pictures and traits? Which API should I use to get transaction history?

Comment: IPFS, arweave these are some decentralized storage protocol that are quite popular, but it depends on the creator as I said.

About APIs, I am not very experienced with this, but I guess some of the best options would be Alchemy, Moralis, Infura, Quicknode etc.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if this helped you and answered your question